# What is word for "complaining without fully understanding"?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, sentence

I have a situation of a co-worker who keeps complaining about process without having a deep/fully understanding  of existing processes, some of things he complains already exist and some don't but with a little reading he can get that information, what is the word or a few words to describe this?

Comment: Such an attitude is 'prejudiced' in one of its senses. Pre-judging. Ultracrepidarian (I found that one at the duplicate.)

Comment: The word is "undertrained".

Comment: @JulesCocovin, It is not. OP needs a word for 'complaining without fully understanding'.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Oh, I might indeed be guilty here of referring to the situation described rather than to the query per se.